# Google Cloud Build always connects to wrong GitHub account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am trying to create a Cloud Build trigger. When I click **Connect Repository** and select **GitHub (Cloud Build GitHub App)** as the source, it always connects to the wrong GitHub account. Unfortunately I was initially signed in to GitHub using my work account rather than the personal account I want to connect to. Now it always lists the repositories I can access from my work GitHub account, even when I return from the add account flow for my personal account.

I have tried clearing all my cookies and using a brand new GCP project, but the problem persists. I'm guessing the GitHub account is linked at the organisation level. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried reproducing your case by following  the steps below

1. I connected Cloud Build to a repository using my GitHub account.
2. I created a new GitHub account for troubleshooting this case.
3. I tried connecting Cloud Build to a repository while using different GitHub account, by selecting "Add new account" option.
4. I signed in the new account on the popped-up window. (Authorizing 2nd account)
5. The account was not added and the repository is still connected to the previous account.

Thus, there is indeed an issue regarding adding a second GitHub account, while connecting Cloud Build to a Repository.

- As a workaround:

  1. I tried revoking access of the GitHub App, via my GitHub account, as stated from @pradeep .
  2. When I revoked the GitHub App access, from my GitHub account (first account I signed in Cloud Build), the second account appeared, but this is not the intended behavior. (On step 4th above I had authorized it to)

     ```
     - Did you succeed in adding the account via this workaround?
     ```

Additionally, I created a [Public Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/145106218) on your behalf, for the purpose of resolving the issue.

This issue report has been forwarded to the Cloud Build engineering team so that they may investigate it, but there is no ETA for a resolution at this time. Future updates regarding this issue will be provided [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/145106218).

You may “star” the Public Issue, so that it gets more visibility and also add your email address to the “CC” section, in order to receive updates on the case.

Comment: Excellent, many thanks! In the meantime I have worked around this by opting to automatically mirror my GitHub repos in Cloud Source.

Answer (score 2):

You can login to your Github account and revoke authentication you have given to your google account.

This should help you https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/reviewing-your-authorized-integrations